# ShowToolPane2Wrapper -> What does this do?

Tags: javascript

I had a piece of code that I was reading from a book and I stumbled upon this line of code:

```
javascript: ShowToolPane2Wrapper('Edit','129','{0}');
```

I tired to look up at various resources but could not get a clear idea of what ShowToolPane2Wrapper did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function responsible for opening the `Edit Panel` of a webPart, and usually used to notify the administrators that the webPart needs a configuration

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for this function name indicates that it has something to do with SharePoint.